# How To Download MP3s In Volley

Tags: android, download, mp3, android-volley

I'm finally comfortable with the Volley networking library for Android, and I can download strings, but not MP3s.

How do I download MP3s with it?

Answer (score 2):

According to Google I/O 2013, you should not use Volley for large payload networking tasks: At 3:50 of [this](https://youtu.be/yhv8l9F44qo) video of google i/o 2013 explains how you should use volley.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your own request then get response as byte array and write it to file. Be sure that you have access to mp3 file. Links below can help you out

http://garena.github.io/blog/2014/07/13/what-works-for-us-so-far-volley/

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html